In Rust, what may cause the numerical error of UnitQuaternion multiplications in succession? How to avoid it?
Assuming that the following function get_correction is defined such that given the first rotation, it can compute the 2nd consecutive rotation that can rotate a 3d vector to the "UP" direction:
    pub fn get_correction(
        acc: Vector3<f32>,
        rotation: UnitQuaternion<f32>,
    ) -> Option<UnitQuaternion<f32>> {
        Self::get_correction_verified(&acc.to_owned(), &rotation.to_owned())
    }

    fn get_correction_raw(
        acc: &Vector3<f32>,
        rotation: &UnitQuaternion<f32>,
    ) -> Option<UnitQuaternion<f32>> {
        static UP_FRD: Vector3<f32> = Vector3::new(0.0, 0.0, -9.81);

        let uncorrected = rotation.transform_vector(&UP_FRD);
        let correction_opt = UnitQuaternion::rotation_between(&uncorrected, &acc);
        correction_opt
    }

    fn get_correction_verified(
        acc: &Vector3<f32>,
        rotation: &UnitQuaternion<f32>,
    ) -> Option<UnitQuaternion<f32>> {
        Self::get_correction_verified_internal(acc, rotation).0
    }

    fn get_correction_verified_internal(
        acc: &Vector3<f32>,
        rotation: &UnitQuaternion<f32>,
    ) -> (Option<UnitQuaternion<f32>>, f32) {
        let raw = Self::get_correction_raw(acc, rotation);
        match raw {
            Some(correction) => {
                //round trip verification
                let corrected = correction * rotation;

                let should_be_zero = Self::get_correction_raw(acc, &corrected);

                let zero = should_be_zero.unwrap().angle();
                if zero > 0.01 {
                    println!("residual={}", zero);
                    println!(
                        "compute: {}, {} => {}",
                        acc.transpose(),
                        rotation,
                        correction
                    );

                    // let again = Self::get_correction_verified_internal(acc, rotation);
                    // assert!((raw, zero) == again)
                }

                (raw, zero)
            }
            None => (raw, 0.0),
        }
    }

to minimise numerical errors, this definition has an elaborated round trip verification to ensure that the divergence after 2 consecutive rotations are close to 0.
When this function is repeatedly tested using a random Vector & Quaternion generator, I found that the roundtrip error gradually deteriorates over time. It starts with 0, then gradually increase to almost 180 degrees. Strangely, if I restart the testing program with the same argument, the roundtrip error will become 0 again. Here is a typical examples of input-output pair of this function:
after 4 minutes, roundtrip error=1.6
      ┌                                     ┐
      │   3.0176868 -0.74084723     9.24847 │
      └                                     ┘
,
     UnitQuaternion angle: 2.262818 − axis: (-0.0015257122, -0.9227901, -0.38530007)

 => UnitQuaternion angle: 1.6769453 − axis: (-0.5872864, -0.79925746, 0.1276015)


restarted with the same data, roundtrip error=0
        compute:
      ┌                                     ┐
      │   3.0176868 -0.74084723     9.24847 │
      └                                     ┘
    , 
UnitQuaternion angle: 2.262818 − axis: (-0.0015257121, -0.92279005, -0.38530007)

 => UnitQuaternion angle: 0.87873745 − axis: (-0.67957145, -0.71493566, 0.16446783)

Since I deliberately created deep copies of all the arguments, I don't think this problem can be caused by mutable states of both arguments. What may have caused this behaviour?
UPDATE 1. After some experiments I'm able to reproduce this error:

#[test]
pub fn __accumulate_unit_quaternion() {
    use rand::Rng;

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let mut qq = UnitQuaternion::from_euler_angles(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    let unit_vec = Vector3::new(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    loop {
        let u1 = rng.gen_range(-1.58f32..1.58);
        let u2 = rng.gen_range(-1.58f32..1.58);
        let u3 = rng.gen_range(-1.58f32..1.58);

        let random = UnitQuaternion::from_euler_angles(u1, u2, u3);

        qq = random * qq;

        let reconstruction_error = {
            let reconstructed = UnitQuaternion::from_axis_angle(&qq.axis().unwrap(), qq.angle());
            let error = (qq * unit_vec - reconstructed * unit_vec).norm();
            error
        };

        println!("error={}", reconstruction_error);

        assert!(reconstruction_error < 0.001);
    }
}

When executing it, we can observe that the reconstruction error of the UnitQuaternion gradually increases until it fails the assertion. My conjecture is that the linear algebra library naively believes that 2 UnitQuaternions can be multiplied directly to yield a UnitQuaternion WITHOUT normalisation, which is true in theory but not true in numerical computation.
How do I rewrite the program to minimise the reconstruction errors? If the above is true, we will need a short-term bypass and a long-term fix for the library.

Please add a [mre].

example added, should I delete the old question?

according to a library maintainer, I need to periodically call:
qq.renormalize()

//OR

qq.renormalize_fast()

they are excluded from being called automatically in every multiplication as they incur a small performance cost.
